# Crossed homomorphisms between power series groups

Tags: group-theory, power-series, group-cohomology, formal-power-series

Consider the group $\mathbb{C}[[z]]_1$ of the power series of the form $a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \cdots$, with $a_1\neq 0$, under the operation of composition, and $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ as a $\mathbb{C}[[z]]_1$-module.

I want to know what are the crossed homomorphisms $\beta: \mathbb{C}[[z]]_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[[z]]$, that is, the functions that satisfy $\beta(h_2\circ h1)=\beta(h1)+\beta(h_2)\circ h_1$

This question is related with group cohomology, since the group $H^1(\mathbb{C}[[z]]_1, \mathbb{C}[[z]])$ is the quotient of the crossed homomorfisms over principal crossed homomorphisms.

That principal crossed homomorphisms are of the form $\beta_g (h) = g\circ h - g$.
I found that there is a crossed homomorphism $\beta (h) = ln(h/z)$ that is not principal, so, my conjecture is that the group  $H^1(\mathbb{C}[[z]]_1, \mathbb{C}[[z]])$ is generated by that element (as $\mathbb{C}$-module). Can anyone help me to prove this (probably using group cohomology techniques)? what moreover results can be extracted using these tools?

Thank you!

Comment: Crossposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215207/crossed-homomorphisms-between-power-series-groups

Comment: can you help me with this problem?